# After-advice for disabling evil-mode in ansi-term has no effect

Tags: evil, advice

I'm using `evil-mode` and trying to make sure that it gets disabled after invoking an `ansi-term`.

I've tried using `before` and `after` advice to advise the `ansi-term` function, as well as adding a hook to `term-mode`, but that doesn't seem to disable evil mode in the ansi-term buffer.

I ended up defining a separate interactive function that calls `ansi-term` with a fixed argument and then disables evil-mode for just the current buffer.

```
(defun ansi-term-disable-evil ()
  "interactively call ansi-term"
  (interactive)
  (ansi-term "/bin/tcsh") ; probably shouldn't be hardcoded
  (evil-local-mode -1))
```

This function has the desired effect (disabling evil-mode in the ansi-term buffer).

Using after advice, however, does not work and I'm trying to understand why.

Here is what I I tried in an attempt to disable evil-mode locally after executing `ansi-term`.

```
(defun ansi-term-post ()
  "configuration settings for ansi-term"
  (evil-local-mode -1))

(advice-add 'ansi-term :after 'ansi-term-post) ; I used an ordinary symbol here, not a function object with #'
```

However, this didn't actually disable evil-mode in the ansi-term buffer. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: I suggest changing your question to ask why the advice doesn't work (and show what advice your tried). Any attempt to redefine a function like you're asking "without advice" is just going to be a reimplementation of the advice system, and will probably have the same trouble.

Comment: @npostavs ... that is not necessarily true. It might be possible to grab the function object associated with the old definition, bind it to a local variable (in the value namespace?), and then `funcall` that value inside the body of the new definition of `ansi-term`. Advice is visible on the advised function, is disable-able, and IIRC there are a fixed number of advice slots on a function. But yeah I'd like to advise a function in such a way that the advised-ness is not visible to the outside world ...

Comment: If you *want to redefine* the function, and you want to completely replace it, then use an around advice or just redefine it using `defun`. Why don't you want to use an around advice? As @npostavs said: show what you've tried and explain what doesn't "work". And say why you do not want "visible" advice.

Comment: "grab the function object associated with the old definition, bind it to a local variable[...] and then funcall that value inside the body of the new definition of ansi-term" - yeah, that's how the advice system works. Or at least the nadvice.el implementation. And, AFAIK, the traditional advice.el is now built on top of it.

Comment: @npostavs ... I rewrote the question to be focused on why the after advice I originally wrote does not fire. My original motivation for not wanting to use advice is that the API exposed by an advice-bearing function is more powerful than I need for this case... and I'm trying to get a better understanding of what the alternatives are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a bug which should trigger an error.  Apparently this error is silenced for some reason, but the error is that your `ansi-term-post` function will be called with the same arguments as `ansi-term` and this function takes at least 1 argument, so your function will be called with one argument, which will fail since your function does not accept any argument.  You need to do something like:

```
(defun ansi-term-post (&rest _)
  "configuration settings for ansi-term"
  (evil-local-mode -1))
```

This said, it's likely that wasamasa's answer is a better option.

Answer (score 7):

Disabling Evil is the wrong approach to this problem, customize the initial state for term instead:

```
(evil-set-initial-state 'term-mode 'emacs)
```